# Regroup a list with Groovy depending on a value of a column

Tags: list, groovy, group-by

I have a list with Street adress , postal code , country , province , etc .....

I would like to redroup All the housenumber for the same street in a row
Something like :

```
City         Street              Cp        Housenumber   etc......
Qc      Rue Prudent-Cloutier   G0E 1V0        1-3,6,9-11
Qc      Rue Godin              G0E 1V0        102-104
.
.
.
.
```

So what i did is to get all unique value for the street colums and add them to a newlist and compare it to the first list with all the value but i always get null value ...

```
def str ='''\

 

<Table>
    <Columns Items="6">
        <Column Name="Id" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Text" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Highlight" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Cursor" Type="Integer"/>
        <Column Name="Description" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Next" Type="String"/>
    </Columns>
    <Rows Items="8">
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|800140112" Text="1 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15635710" Text="3 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|21493732" Text="6 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|16097589" Text="9 Rte Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|17847787" Text="11 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997187" Text="102 Rue Municipale" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997137" Text="102 Rue Godin" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997149" Text="104 Rue Godin" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>   
    </Rows>

</Table>

 

'''
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(str)
List newAddressList=new ArrayList();
List StreetsAdress=new ArrayList();
List newUniqueList=new ArrayList();
def iter_String = xml.Rows[0].@Items
int iter = new Integer(iter_String).intValue()
z=0
for (int i=0; i < iter ; i++){
    LastId = xml.Rows[0].Row[i].@Id
    def (Country, Type) = LastId.tokenize( '\\|' )
    Text = xml.Rows[0].Row[i].@Text
    def (HouseNumber, Street) = Text.split(" " ,2)
    if (HouseNumber!="CP"){
    Description = xml.Rows[0].Row[i].@Description
    def (City,City_ab,Code_postale ) = Description.tokenize( ',' )
    newAddressList.add(['RecordId1':z++,'Country1 ':Country,'HouseNumber1':HouseNumber,'Street1': Street,'City1':City,'City_ab1':City_ab,'Code_postale1':Code_postale]);
    StreetsAdress.add(['StreetList':Street]);
    newUniqueList = StreetsAdress.unique();
    }
}
println newUniqueList
```

So i was wondering how i can compare newUniqueList(contain only streets with no duplicate) and newAddressList ( with all the informations) and regroup all houseNumbers . Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def data = '''
<Table>
    <Columns Items="6">
        <Column Name="Id" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Text" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Highlight" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Cursor" Type="Integer"/>
        <Column Name="Description" Type="String"/>
        <Column Name="Next" Type="String"/>
    </Columns>
    <Rows Items="8">
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|800140112" Text="1 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15635710" Text="3 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|21493732" Text="6 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|16097589" Text="9 Rte Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|17847787" Text="11 Rue Prudent-Cloutier" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997187" Text="102 Rue Municipale" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997137" Text="102 Rue Godin" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>
        <Row Id="CA|CP|A|15997149" Text="104 Rue Godin" Highlight="" Cursor="0" Description="Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0" Next="Retrieve"/>   
    </Rows>
</Table>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data) 

def collapsed = xml.Rows.Row.groupBy { row -> 
  def matcher = row.@Text =~ /[^0-9]+/
  matcher[0]
}.collect { street, rows -> 
  def nums = rows.collect { row -> 
    row.@Text.text().tokenize(' ').first() as Integer
  }.sort()

  def tokens = rows.first().@Description.text().tokenize(',')
  def range = nums.size() == 1 ? "${nums.first()}" : "${nums.first()}-${nums.last()}"
  [City: tokens[1].trim(), Street: street.trim(), Cp: tokens[2].trim(), HouseNumber: range]
}


def headers = ['City', 'Street', 'Cp', 'HouseNumber']
def widths = headers.collectEntries { header -> 
  [header, collapsed.collect { it[header].length() }.max() + 4]
}

headers.each { header ->
  print(header.padRight(widths[header]))
}
println()

collapsed.each { row -> 
  headers.each { header -> 
    print(row[header].padRight(widths[header]))
  }
  println()
}
```

when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
City  Street                      Cp         HouseNumber
QC    Rue Prudent-Cloutier        G0E 1V0    1-11
QC    Rte Rue Prudent-Cloutier    G0E 1V0    9
QC    Rue Municipale              G0E 1V0    102
QC    Rue Godin                   G0E 1V0    102-104
```

...went the extra mile and did some formatting of the output which complicates the solution, but this should give you an example of how you can work with this.

As this is somewhat complicated, I'll add some explanation for the main part of the code.

Explanation:

```
xml.Rows.Row.groupBy { row -> 
  def matcher = row.@Text =~ /[^0-9]+/
  matcher[0]
}
```

this will take the list of rows returned by `xml.Rows.Row` and group them on the non-numeric part of Row.Text (i.e. the street name without the number, example: "Rue Prudent-Cloutier"). `groupBy` returns a `Map<street name, List<Row>`, in other words, the rows grouped by what street the address is on (excluding the number).

```
.collect { street, rows -> 
  ...
}
```

this will iterate through the `Map<street name, List<Row>>` and create a list. In other words for each street, this closure (the part inside the `{ }`) will be called once with the street name ("Rue Prudent-Cloutier") and all the rows which have that street name in the `rows` list. The `collect` will return a `List<something>` where `something` is whatever this closure returns.

```
  def nums = rows.collect { row -> 
    row.@Text.text().tokenize(' ').first() as Integer
  }.sort()
```

Takes all the rows for a specific street such as "Rue Prudent-Cloutier", extracts the street numbers (1, 3, etc), converts them into integers and sorts then so that `nums` is a `List<Integer>` with the smallest number first and the largest last.

```
  def tokens = rows.first().@Description.text().tokenize(',')
```

Splits the description text such as `Mont-Saint-Pierre, QC, G0E 1V0` on comma returning a `List<String>` (in this example `['Mont-Saint-Pierre', 'QC', 'G0E 1V0']).

```
  def range = nums.size() == 1 ? "${nums.first()}" : "${nums.first()}-${nums.last()}"
```

Takes the sorted house numbers and creates either a single digit string `9` or a range string `1-11` and stores it in variable `range`.

```
[City: tokens[1].trim(), Street: street.trim(), Cp: tokens[2].trim(), HouseNumber: range]
```

This finally creates the return value from the `.collect { street, rows -> ... }`. This is groovy map syntax, in other words, each iteration in the collect will return a map and `collapsed` will therefore have type `List<Map<String, String>>`, or perhaps simpler with an example, `collapsed` will have this structure:

```
[[City: QC, Street: Rue Prudent-Cloutier, Cp: G0E 1V0, HouseNumber:1-11],
 [City: QC, Street: Rue Municipale, Cp: G0E 1V0, HouseNumber:102]
 ...
]
```

As for where you should put your condition, I think you will have to modify to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer this will save me a lot of night since im a begginer . Still i have a question if the initial list of housenumber contain sometime  Strings like "CP" or "104A... can u just tell me where i am supposed to put my condition . In my version i have it aftre the def(HouseNumber...Thank you again and i will show you the final result when im done ... :)